# Select Image from Gallery RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException` when i am trying to select store the image from gallery to imageview.i am using two intents.

1.Take Picture and store in imageview
2.choose from gallery

But when i am using this code [MainActivity.java](http://pastie.org/4616026) i am getting that exception in stoing the image of camera and when i am using this code [MainActivity.java](http://pastie.org/4615999) then getting the error in storing the image of gallery.
What is the wrong on that codes.

if it works for camera image then its not work for gallery and if its work for gallery then not working for camera images . why?

Here is my log cat of setting image of camera.

```
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {org.inextrix.userprofile/org.inextrix.userprofile.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at org.inextrix.userprofile.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:77)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
08-30 17:37:57.218: E/AndroidRuntime(8877):     ... 11 more
```

Anyone had this problem before or i am doing something wrong. if you any idea then suggest me
Thanks

Comment: The error says that the data was not received properly from the Intent.

Comment: post MainActivity.java:77 line number code

Comment: Show this line of code: MainActivity.java:77

Comment: Source code can be found from Pastie links he provided.

Comment: i have provided the both source files